# Spring security when I try to get jwt token second time, it returns forbidden

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I enabled spring security. I have 2 users in my userDetails service. I have an authentication endpoint `/api/v1/auth/authenticate`. This endpoint is not secured.

I start the application and hit send button in postman. It returns the JWT token. When I click send right after, it returns `403`.

After these steps, I entered the credentials of the second user in postman request. I hit the send request button. `JWT` token returned normally. When I clicked send button the second time, it returns `403`.

I am able to access secured endpoints normally using the `JWT`.

I restarted the server, Again I am able to call and get `JWT` token but I can get it only once, the other attempts to generate `JWT` token results in a `403` response.

When I debugged the application, it gets bad credentials exception in this line

```
authenticationManager.authenticate(
   new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        request.getEmail(), request.getPassword()
    )
);
```

it doesn't print the exception to the console. Even if the credentials are correct (I don't change request body between the first and second attempt to get JWT.) the response is 403 in the second attempt.

Why is that?

I use spring boot 3.1.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

my userdetails service is:

```java
@Component
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final static List<UserDetails> APPLICATION_USERS = Arrays.asList(
            new User(
                "ylozsoy@gmail.com",
                "password",
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))
            ),
            new User(
                    "yilmazozsoy@gmail.com",
                    "password2",
                    Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))
            )
    );

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return APPLICATION_USERS
                .stream()
                .filter(u -> u.getUsername().equals(email))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user was found for email: " + email));
    }
}
```

It is breaking here
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4iqH.png)

At the first call this looks like :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZvjD.png)

At the second call, password is gone
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctggZ.png)

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
    String userEmail;
    String jwtToken;
    if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    jwtToken = authHeader.substring(7);
    userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwtToken);
    if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
        if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request){
    authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword())
    );
    final UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getEmail());
    if (user != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(jwtService.generateToken(user));
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(400).body("Some error has occured");
}
```

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());
    http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> {
        requests.requestMatchers(antMatcher("/api/v1/auth/**"))
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    });
    http.sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```

pom.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springbootdemoweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5-b10</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[This is the complete project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/files/11599537/Archive.zip).

Comment: which spring boot version you're using?

Comment: You've said that `/api/v1/auth/authenticate` is not secured, but your security configuration uses `/api/v1/auth/**` and you are getting a 403 response which suggests that it is secured. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve) that shows exactly how to reproduce the behavior you have described?

Comment: I posted all the codes I am using. It looks like that spring boot tries to protect the passwords but completely deletes them.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security avoids holding credentials, such as a password, in memory for any longer than necessary. This is implemented using the `eraseCredentials()` method that `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` implements. Your list of `User`s is held in a static field so the two `User` instances are re-used. Once the credentials have been erased, this makes the `User` useless.

Rather than creating your own in-memory `UserDetailsService` implementation,  I would use Spring Security's `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` instead.